# Does index on string column impact on where clause when providing only part of string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's start with example:

`select title from books where name ilike '% of the rings';`

If i create index on column title it will upgrade my performance or only if full correct string is provided in query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Comment: No, it won't. The search pattern should not start with a wildcard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a standard index, Postgres should be able to use the index when the `like` pattern starts with a constant.  That would be:

```
where name like 'Lord of the %'
```

A standard index is not used when the pattern starts with a wildcard, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html):

> The optimizer can also use a B-tree index for queries involving the pattern matching operators LIKE and ~ if the pattern is a constant and is anchored to the beginning of the string — for example, col LIKE 'foo%' or col ~ '^foo', but not col LIKE '%bar'.

As a general rule, though, this does not extend to `ilike` (although there are exceptions explained in the documentation).

Postgres offers other indexes (such a GIN indexes and trigram indexes) that can be used to speed such queries.